How much do Redis Modules allow us to change
So in an ideal world , I would like to replace some very low level stuff . For instance the 'zmalloc' , some of them I want to replace with my own version of malloc , and I also get to know which areas of memory has been changed and so on .There is little chance thats possible only via Modules , but if it was , it would be great .
I tried playing with Modules and doing some undef of zmalloc and define my own version . And I also did some gdb to see what Redis calls for certain stuff
